# How to plot min and max of two columns per row as a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
| id | length_bgn | length_end |
--------------------------------
| 1  |   209      |    215     |
| 2  |   324      |    125     |
| 3  |   167      |    156     |
| .. |   ...      |    ...     |
--------------------------------
```

I would like to make a scatterplot with the minimum of the length (per row) on the X-axis and the maximum per row on the Y axis. I have tried:

```
qplot(min(length_bgn, length_end), max(length_bgn, length_end), data=df)
```

However this plots a single point of the minimum of both columns against the maximum of both columns. Am I using the wrong functions? Or would it be better to manipulate the dataframe somehow? Please excuse any naivety, I am still quite new to R and ggplot2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Example plot using the above code:

[image: example scatterplot]

Comment: You're going to have to be much clearer in your explanation. I see only three values per row in your df, and only one of those is length_bgn. What are you taking the min over?

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to plot, for example for id==2, x=125 and y=324. I.e. I would like to have the minimum per-row against the maximum per-row. I hope that is clearer but let me know if not.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You're going to need to rearrange your df so that the columns correspond to the variables you want to plot. i.e. the min in each row should all be in one column. I would investigate using `apply` twice.

Comment: The id column is unique. That is what I meant, the min(length_bgn, length_end), as in the min between those two columns, per row.

I am just not sure how to do this properly in ggplot2; I will post an example plot of what I get if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
library("ggplot2")

df <- read.table(text = " id  length_bgn  length_end 
        1     209          215     
 2     324          125     
 3     167          156     ", header=TRUE)

df$x <- apply(df[,c(2,3)], 1, min)
df$y <- apply(df[,c(2,3)], 1, max)


qplot(x, y, data=df)
```

Answer (score 3):

@gauden's solution is good (to do the processing before plotting), but if you really want `ggplot` to do that work for you too, you can. [Using `df` that @gauden provided.]

```
qplot(pmin(length_bgn, length_end), pmax(length_bgn, length_end), data=df)
```

[image]